# filtering rows from mysql column if it does not exist in other table query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables and i want to get the result if it exists in tableA only
for example you can  see that in tableA 081 ID does not exist but in tableB column it exist
so if we do this query

```
 tableA table



 ID    SID         actions
   08     60420       082
   08     60420       083
   08     60420       084
```

but in  my query for above output is

```
   SELECT * FROM tableB where SID='60420' and PID='08' order by id desc limit 10

 tableB 


  ID      SID      PID
  081     60420      08 
  082     60420      08 
  083     60420      08 
  084     60420      08
```

PID of tableB and ID of tableA are same as you can see in output. SID is also same for particular customer
how can  i ensure that it removes 081 rows from the output as it is not existing in tableA
or is it possible i delete 081 rows from tableB so that my query still works without any issue
i tried join but as SID is not unique it results in many rows as output
should i try distinct ?? i did not try distinct as it may have some performance issues
any help will be great

Comment: *and parent='08'* - check what you have posted, you have no column called *parent*

Comment: @Stu sorry it was mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want rows from TableB but only where there exists a correlation, so use *exists*

```
select * 
from tableB b
where b.SID='60420' and b.PID='08' 
    and exists (select * from tableA a where a.actions=b.ID and a.SID=b.SID)
order by b.id desc 
limit 10;
```

Comment: The title suggests that `NOT EXISTS` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply join two tables with inner join. In MySQL inner join works with keyword `JOIN`. It will exclude rows which don't exist in other table or in other words, will show only rows which exist in both tables:

```
SELECT tableB.*
FROM tableB 
JOIN tableA
  ON tableA.actions = tableB.ID
    AND tableA.SID = tableB.SID
    AND tableA.ID = tableB.PID
WHERE SID='60420'
  AND PID='08'
ORDER BY tableB.ID desc
LIMIT 10
```